# How to convert unsigned char * to QString

Tags: c, qt

I know this is a very basic question but sometimes it happens that you loose your basic concept :) 
Tried Goggling but not enough support on that too.

I am using predefined library from one of our device owner. They have a declaration as :

```
unsigned char FamilySerialNum[0][8]
```

This variable gets the serial number of the device in hexadecimal. Now i am using this library  in Qt to display the serial number in QLineEdit. For that I need to convert it to QString.

Tried using QString::UTF8, strcpy(), sprintf() etc. but getting garbage data.

So can anyone suggest me some way to get it done.

Comment: Can you try with: QString var = new QString( char* varTwo );?

Comment: @facunvd, I tried with your suggestion. It gives an error "conversion from 'QString*' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested

Comment: @Steve-o, I know its not C but we should find some way to use C in Qt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Hello Try the function below...

```
QString getStringFromUnsignedChar(unsigned char *str)
{

    QString s;
    QString result = "";
    int rev = strlen(str); 

    // Print String in Reverse order....
    for ( int i = 0; i<rev; i++)
        {
           s = QString("%1").arg(str[i],0,16);

           if(s == "0"){
              s="00";
             }
         result.append(s);

         }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

User1550798's answer is very close but doesn't quite work (some outputs it produces are corrupted), since it only converts the value "0" to a zero-padded 2 character output (ie: "00"). Instead any single-digit hex values should be be padded with a zero (ie: "3" --> "03").

Try the following instead:

```
QString getStringFromUnsignedChar( unsigned char *str ){
    QString result = "";
    int lengthOfString = strlen( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str) );

    // print string in reverse order
    QString s;
    for( int i = 0; i < lengthOfString; i++ ){
        s = QString( "%1" ).arg( str[i], 0, 16 );

        // account for single-digit hex values (always must serialize as two digits)
        if( s.length() == 1 )
            result.append( "0" );

        result.append( s );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can this operation be reversed? I need to convert 'unsigned char *str' to QString to save it in a file. But I need to reverse the operation to use 'unsigned char *str' in an operation.

Answer (score 0):

int lengthOfString = strlen( reinterpret_cast(str) );//bug,when try to get the length like "00889966"

```
QString getStringFromUnsignedChar( unsigned char *str, const int len ){
    QString result = "";
    int lengthOfString = len  );

    // print string in reverse order
    QString s;
    for( int i = 0; i < lengthOfString; i++ ){
        s = QString( "%1" ).arg( str[i], 0, 16 );

        // account for single-digit hex values (always must serialize as two digits)
        if( s.length() == 1 )
            result.append( "0" );

        result.append( s );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From unsigned char* to QString:

```
unsigned char *str_uchar;
QString str = QString::fromUtf8((char*)str_uchar);
```

From QString to unsigned char*:

```
QString str;
unsigned char *str_uchar = (unsigned char*)(str.toUtf8().data());
```

Comment: The last line can crash the application because the QByteArray (`str.toUtf8().data()`) was created periodically!